# boolean inside useRef is not giving correct value and it is always false

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Boolean inside useRef is not giving correct value, and it is always false in React/React native. Even if the keyboard is present isKeyboardShown inside **keyboardDissmissPanResponder = useRef** is always false

```js
const isKeyboardShown = keyboardState?.isKeyboardShown ?? false;

const keyboardDissmissPanResponder = useRef(
  PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (_e, gestureState) => {
      const isHorizonSwipe = Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy);
      return isHorizonSwipe && isKeyboardShown;
    },
    onPanResponderGrant: Keyboard.dismiss,
  }),
).current;
```

How can I fix it? If someone knows what went wrong then please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Note that your `isKeyboardShown` is just a random variable, and React doesn't know about it. As such, updating it won't signal anything to React either.

Answer (score 1):

That code will only run once. `isKeyboardShown` will never change value. I'd recommend using state.

If you make it a state then the value will always be updated, something like this:

```js
const [isKeyboardShown, setIsKeyboardShown] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   setIsKeyboardShown(keyboardState?.isKeyboardShown ?? false);
}, [keyboardState]);
```

I'm assuming the `keyboardState` is an actual state.

You can learn more about react state's [here](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory).

Answer (score 0):

`isKeyboardShown` is always false or never updates because it's a stale Javascript closure over it in the `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` callback handler. The `useRef` is initially set to the value passed to it, the `PanResponder` object, and *that* ref's initial `current` value is saved to `keyboardDissmissPanResponder`.

From what I can understand it seems you really just want to provide a stable `PanResponder` object. Use the `useMemo` hook to create the stable reference with a dependency on the `keyboardState` reference. Each time the `keyboardState` reference updates, a new `PanResponder` object is created and returned for use in the UI.

Example:

```js
const keyboardDismissPanResponder = React.useMemo(() => {
  const isKeyboardShown = keyboardState?.isKeyboardShown ?? false;

  return PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (_e, ({ dx, dy })) => {
      const isHorizonSwipe = Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy);
          
      return isHorizonSwipe && isKeyboardShown;
    },
    onPanResponderGrant: Keyboard.dismiss,
  }),
}, [keyboardState]);
```

In some cases where consumers internalize the handlers and don't react to new instances you may need to take a slightly different approach. Use a React ref to cache the current `keyboardState` value so the ref can be referenced in the `PanResponder` handlers. This removes `keyboardState` as an external dependency for the `PanResponder` memoization.

Example:

```js
const keyboardStateRef = useRef(keyboardState);

React.useEffect(() => {
  keyboardStateRef.current = keyboardState;
}, [keyboardState]);

const keyboardDismissPanResponder = React.useMemo(() => {
  return PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (_e, ({ dx, dy })) => {
      const isKeyboardShown = keyboardStateRef.current?.isKeyboardShown ?? false;
      const isHorizonSwipe = Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy);
          
      return isHorizonSwipe && isKeyboardShown;
    },
    onPanResponderGrant: Keyboard.dismiss,
  }),
}, []);
```